# Getting a warning while adding external JavaScript library in SP2013 Napa developer tool

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, app, office-365-develop-tool

I m getting warning while adding external JavaScript library added within ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" in SP2013 Napa developer tool
Warning Message obtained from Chrome developer tool - 
[blocked] The page at "App Url" ran insecure content from http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp.

Due to this warning message I m not able to consume the geoplugin webservice inside my app as all the function call are leading to undefined objects.

Is there a fix to this issue or am I missing something here. Please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This error occured because you use non SSL-secured protocol http instead of https. Try to use following url: https://ssl.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp. If you get 403 error try to use XML web service: https://ssl.geoplugin.net/xml.gp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link.

I tried it in My SP 2013 App. It Worked for me.

http://html5demos.com/geo